# As a US citizen how long can I stay in Malaysia and what do I need to do to extend the time?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, malaysia

I know I'll need my passport and a visitors visa. And I think that's about 90 days. Is there any way I can get a longer stay?

Comment: Why do you want to stay in Malaysia longer?  There are other visa options for working, visiting family, retirement, etc.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.